# My Javascript isn't printing anything

Tags: javascript, html

My code isn't printing anything. I am trying to print current time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function print(){
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.gethours();
        var seconds = now.getSeconds();
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "<br/>");
    }
    setInterval("print()", 1000);       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `var hours = now.gethours();` to `var hours = now.getHours();`

Answer (score 1):

When testing your JavaScript code use:

```
alert("output: " + var);
```

Or in the developer console

```
console.log(var);
```

So you can see output or erros

Comment: Hello, actually I'm new to html and javascript, I don't understand how the alert("output: " + var) works, can you tell me what it is. Though I wrote this  function in the script and nothing happened.